# Queries performances on ADLS gen 2

Tags: data-warehouse, azure-data-lake, external-tables, azure-synapse

I'm trying to migrate our "old school" database (mostly time series) to an Azure Data Lake.

So I took a random table (10 years of data, 200m records, 20Gb), copied the data in a single csv file AND also to the same data and created 4000 daily files (in monthly folders).

On top of those 2 sets of files, I created 2 external tables.... and i'm getting pretty much the same performance for both of them. (?!?)

No matter what I'm querying, whether I'm looking for data on a single day (thus in a single small file) or making summation of the whole dataset... it basically takes 3 minutes, no matter if I'm looking at a single file or the daily files (4000). It's as if the whole dataset had to be loaded into memory before doing anything ?!?

**So is there a setting somewhere that I could change so avoid having load all the data when it's not required??** It could literally make my queries 1000x faster.

As far as I understand, indexes are not possible on External tables. Creating a materialized view will defeat the purpose of using a Lake. t

Full disclosure; I'm new to Azure Data Storage, I'm trying to see if it's the correct technology to address our issue.

Comment: What query engine are you using in Synapse? SQL (DW) Pool or SQL On-demand? Or Spark?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to use Parquet format, not CSV. It is a columnar format optimized for OLAP-like queries.

With Synapse Preview, you can then use SQL on-demand engine (serverless technology) when you do not need to provision DW cluster and you will be charged per Tb of scanned data.

Or you can spin up Synapse cluster and ingest your data using COPY command into DW (it is in preview as well).